# Open an external URL

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I am developing a Vuejs application in which I need to display the url for a company. I am displaying it like below:

```
<a :href="company.website">{{company.website}}</a>
```

and `company.website` holds the value `www.companyname.com`.

Whenever I click on the link, it opens with the localhost url appended like below:

`http://localhost:2000/www.companyname.com`

How to make it just open company url?

PS: I know that adding`http or https` to the url solves the issue. I would like to know if there is any other way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use a url like this :

```
//www.companyname.com
```

```js
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
        url: "www.bing.com",
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo" v-cloak>
   <a :href="url">url 1</a>
   <a :href="'//' + url">url 2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution. Thanks. May be you can add it to answer.

Comment: @Pradeepb This is absolutely a valid URL. It is called a protocol-relative URL although whenever possible everyone should be hard-coding `https` for additional security.

Comment: @landro True. I was not aware of that back then. I am extensively using it in my current project.